Returning to graduate school after an unsuccessful PhD
In 2020, I enrolled in an American PhD program in pure mathematics, which went very poorly with no one to blame other than myself. I didn't accomplish very much or build any lasting relationships with the faculty there: I spent the first year doing coursework remotely during a pretty devastating mental health spiral, and ended up getting hospitalized and taking a leave of absence (which has since led to me fully dropping out of the program) during the first quarter back on campus.
I've mostly accepted that this sequence of events has foreclosed any professional involvement with academia, and have done my best to move forward with my life and find other things. It's still a singular passion for me though, and losing my chance to participate in research mathematics so early on in that process is something that I know I would deeply regret.
I'm considering reapplying to graduate schools during next year's admissions cycles, but I'm not sure if "unceremoniously dropped out of a previous PhD" is something that I can feasibly overcome in the admissions process, especially since I have no one I can ask at that institution to even write me a letter of recommendation.
How realistic is it to pursue another funded PhD? If I do decide to have another go at academia, does anybody have any advice on how I should approach that process differently given my situation and history?

There was the whole Covid thing which impacted many people. Go for it.

You will need letters from people who can honestly predict your success. Do you have those? Can you develop such relationships?

Do you have a masters? If so, maybe try to go for a masters program first and then after finishing that go into a PhD program.

‘I struggle deeply to imagine long-term happiness for myself that doesn't involve some participation in research mathematics.’ I think you’re selling yourself short, imagining your future happiness depends strongly on, what’s often, a crap-shoot. Don’t do that to yourself.

Yes - you should keep in mind that a majority of PhDs in mathematics write 0 or 1 papers in their entire careers.  Getting to continue to participate in research mathematics after finishing a PhD is against the odds.

This question is similar to: How are Ph.D. applications evaluated in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students? Am I likely to get into school X?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If at first you don't succeed, try try again
Failure at a thing once does not preclude doing better at it in a subsequent attempt and ultimately succeeding (recognition of which is virtually the entire basis for education).  As far as admission to a new PhD program is concerned, you need to consider a few (related) things:

What, if any, changes have occurred in your life and/or life skills such that you would now either avoid or successfully manage the mental health issues that were causing you grief?

What, if any, changes have occurred in your life and/or life skills such that you would now succeed in a PhD program instead of failing?

Can you plausibly demonstrate any of these changes through some participation in courses and/or research training at a lower level than a PhD program?

Can you (either now or after that) plausibly convince any of your potential referees to write you a letter of recommendation that will indicate a reasonable prospect of success?


As to your broader desire and passion to do research mathematics, you should bear in mind that this is not synonymous with an academic research position.  Modern academia is extremely competitive and very few PhDs get research careers in academia, so even if you complete your PhD successfully there is a reasonable prospect that you might have to do research mathematics only/primarily as a hobby rather than as a career.

Great answer. Here's one interesting data point on failing and then succeeding: this guy applied to become an astronaut three times, succeeding on his third attempt.

You have to remember that a PhD is one of the hardest intellectual and psychological challenges you can face. This is even more true if the program was remote, which we all know has a higher impact on our mental health, and if it was during COVID.
Moreover, building connections is harder if you work remotely. My personal experience is that building connections in academia is generally hard. Many researchers are willing to connect only if you have some work they can take part in or if you have reached a certain status (h-index, published in a specific conference, you name it).
I'm a PhD candidate in computer science, so I can't say much about your field. However, I can say that this is my second PhD. I dropped my first position (after two years) to pursue this one in another country, with better funding and a better institution. The admission office was really understanding of my situation, and I just tried to be upfront about why I was moving on and why I wanted to give up on two years of research. Also, what helped me a lot was that my current supervisor agreed with what I was doing and supported me throughout the process.
Don't give up if you feel that academia and research are what you are looking for. Maybe try to find a program that better suits you, or perhaps one that can better assist you so you don't face the same things again.
(I didn't want to repeat any other answer points, but they are all valid. I just wanted to give the perspective of someone who had a bad time during their first PhD and moved on)
